# How to get input element from Literal

Tags: c#, asp.net

On the sever side, I've created, a literal with text set to an input type file element with `runat = 'server'` property, mode set to `passThrough` and append it to a div. Both the literal and input element have it's own unique id. My issue is trying to get that input element from the div tag. I'm able to get the literal programmatically, but the literal doesn't contain any controls and text value has the input element I need. I tried looking for the input element o it's own and keep getting null. I've inspected the page and I see the input element with `runat='server'`and it's and yet I can't get it. I need to be able to get this input element in order to upload it's file.

This is what I've tried so far:

Client-Side:

```
<div runat="server" id="docRequeridosMainDiv" style="display: table; 
width: 60%; text-align: right">

            <%-- Control set on server side --%>

</div>
```

Server-Side: (Testing this on pageload event)

```
//Attach inivisible input type file
 uploadLit.Text += string.Format(@"<div><input type='file' id='{0}File' runat = 'server' style='display: none;' 
     onchange='" + docsRequeridos.ElementAt(i).Nombre + @"FileSelected()' /></div>", lbl.Text);

uploadLit.ID = lbl.Text + "FileLit";

docRequeridosMainDiv.Controls.Add(uploadLit);

//var lit = (Literal)docRequeridosMainDiv.FindControl(uploadLit.ID);

var lit = (HtmlGenericControl)docRequeridosMainDiv.FindControl(lbl.Text +"File");
```

Ignore the event attached to input, that works.

I've debugged the commented `lit` and on the controls collection has 0 but the text has the input. The second lit is returns a null value.

Tried getting it with the same `Findcontrol` line on a click event and still same result. Literal with no controls.

Just in case you're wondering why the input is `display:none` cause I'm doing a custom file upload, but that's not important cause every other functionality works, the only on that doesn't work is this one.

Comment: `FindControl()` will find only server-controls. The way you have added that file uploader is _not_ a server control. You should use `HtmlInputFile` instead (_without_ that literal).

Comment: what do you mean? Can you elaborate or give me an example

Comment: Adding the words runat=server to your literal doesnt make it a server control. You are just writing those words to the page, the server doesn't process them to hold any meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindControl()` will find only server controls. Adding html control (with `runat="server"` as string) into a `Literal` will not make those controls *servier-side*. But you can use `HtmlInputFile` to achieve the same, like this:

```
var fileInput = new HtmlFileInput
{
    ID = lbl.Text + "File"
};

fileInput.Attributes["onchange"] = docsRequeridos.ElementAt(i).Nombre + "FileSelected()";
fileInput.Attributes["style"] = "display:none";

docRequeridosMainDiv.Controls.Add(fileInput);
```

Now, you can find this control like:

```
var foundFileInput = docRequeridosMainDiv.FindControl(lbl.Text +"File") as HtmlFileInput;
```

If you want to wrap this file input with `div`, you need to make another `HtmlGenericControl` and add that `fileInput` to that; like this:

```
var myDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div")
{
    ID = "FileUploadContainer"
};

myDiv.Controls.Add(fileInput);
docRequeridosMainDiv.Controls.Add(myDiv); // Add myDiv instead of fileInput
```

This will generate exactly the html you wanted, but just programmatically (not with `Literal` string), and controls are now *server-side*.

Comment: Applying your logic worked, I managed to retrieve input control. But, I have a new problem. After I select a file on this input, I'm retrieving the htmlinput control, but the posted file is null even though it's selected. I can see the file's name I selected on the page it's self.

Comment: I'll mark this as answer cause I changed everything and reverted to using fileupload, but this was close to solving it.